# Unable to change font in table to qcr using renewcommand{\ttdefault}{qcr}

Tags: tables, fonts, tabu, fontfamily

### 1

Suppose I have the following commands in my preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength\textwidth{6.5in}
\setlength\textheight{10in}\setlength\oddsidemargin{(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2 - 1in}
\setlength\topmargin{(\paperheight-\textheight-\headheight-\headsep-\footskip)/2 - 1in}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, array}
\usepackage{tabu, colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\minted}{\VerbatimEnvironment}{\VerbatimEnvironment\let\itshape\relax}{}{}
\usemintedstyle{bw}
```

### 2

Now I create some random table:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{qcr}
\begin{tabular}{rrlllrlllrllllrlrllrrrrrrrlrllllrrrrlr}
% border
 & STATE\_\_ & BGN\_DATE & BGN\_TIME & TIME\_ZONE & COUNTY & COUNTYNAME & STATE & EVTYPE & BGN\_RANGE & BGN\_AZI & BGN\_LOCATI & END\_DATE & END\_TIME & COUNTY\_END & COUNTYENDN & END\_RANGE & END\_AZI & END\_LOCATI & LENGTH & WIDTH & F & MAG & FATALITIES & INJURIES & PROPDMG & PROPDMGEXP & CROPDMG & CROPDMGEXP & WFO & STATEOFFIC & ZONENAMES & LATITUDE & LONGITUDE & LATITUDE\_E & LONGITUDE\_ & REMARKS & REFNUM \\ 
  \hline
  1 & 1.00 & 4/18/1950 0:00:00 & 0130 & CST & 97.00 & MOBILE & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 14.00 & 100.00 & 3.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 15.00 & 25.00 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3040.00 & 8812.00 & 3051.00 & 8806.00 &  & 1.00 \\ 
  2 & 1.00 & 4/18/1950 0:00:00 & 0145 & CST & 3.00 & BALDWIN & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 2.00 & 150.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3042.00 & 8755.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 2.00 \\ 
  3 & 1.00 & 2/20/1951 0:00:00 & 1600 & CST & 57.00 & FAYETTE & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 0.10 & 123.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.00 & 25.00 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3340.00 & 8742.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 3.00 \\ 
  4 & 1.00 & 6/8/1951 0:00:00 & 0900 & CST & 89.00 & MADISON & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 0.00 & 100.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3458.00 & 8626.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 4.00 \\ 
  5 & 1.00 & 11/15/1951 0:00:00 & 1500 & CST & 43.00 & CULLMAN & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 0.00 & 150.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3412.00 & 8642.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 5.00 \\ 
  6 & 1.00 & 11/15/1951 0:00:00 & 2000 & CST & 77.00 & LAUDERDALE & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 1.50 & 177.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 6.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3450.00 & 8748.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 6.00 \\ 
% border
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However, notice that `\footnotesize` is applied to all elements in the table, but `qcr` front is not. What did I do wrong?

Comment: you are missing a \ttfamily command to actually call the typewriter font.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Should I place `\ttfamily` before or after `\ttdefault`?

Comment: These are only two variants, so why don't try both and compares the results?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I was able to solve my issue. Many thanks!

Comment: The `tabular` environment appears to contain 38 columns. Just out of idle curiosity: How wide is the text block of your document? Between 25 and 30 inches?

Comment: @Mico I am not familiar with the ins-and-outs of LaTeX. So I do not know how to address your question. I am having issues using `\scalebox{0.5}{\...}` to reduce the scale of my table. Any help would be great.

Comment: What's your document's paper size? How wide are the margins?

Comment: @MichaelŠòdéké Even with `\tiny`, I still get over than 1000pt beyond the margin, that is, 35cm (14 inches). There's no scaling trick that can make this table to fit on reasonable paper width and to keep it readable.

Comment: @egreg I fixed that issue: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568169/how-to-use-scalebox-on-table-to-avoid-table-cutting-off-from-page/568174#568174](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568169/how-to-use-scalebox-on-table-to-avoid-table-cutting-off-from-page/568174#568174)

Answer (score 1):

Tf you want TeX Gyre Cursor to be the default monospace font for the entire document, you want to set `\ttdefault` once, in your preamble.  That’s much simpler and less error-prone.  Then, `\texttt` or `\ttfamily` will work correctly throughout.

If you want to use multiple monospace fonts, you do *not* want to redefine `\ttdefault` each time.  You can add the commands

```
\newcommand\courierfamily{\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textcourier{\courierfamily}
```

Then `\courierfamily` and `\textcourier` will work like `\ttfamily` and `\texttt`.  (Or `\crfamily`, `\courier` or whatever you prefer.)  If you ever update to LuaTeX or XeTeX, or want to change your fonts, you can change the definition of `\courierfamily` to `\newfontfamily\courierfamily{TeX Gyre Cursor}`, and not have to change the body of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you `@Ulrike Fischer` for your help. I figured out a way fix my issue.

The key is to call `\ttfamily` underneath `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{qcr}`:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{qcr}
\ttfamily
\begin{tabular}{rrlllrlllrllllrlrllrrrrrrrlrllllrrrrlr}
% border
 & STATE\_\_ & BGN\_DATE & BGN\_TIME & TIME\_ZONE & COUNTY & COUNTYNAME & STATE & EVTYPE & BGN\_RANGE & BGN\_AZI & BGN\_LOCATI & END\_DATE & END\_TIME & COUNTY\_END & COUNTYENDN & END\_RANGE & END\_AZI & END\_LOCATI & LENGTH & WIDTH & F & MAG & FATALITIES & INJURIES & PROPDMG & PROPDMGEXP & CROPDMG & CROPDMGEXP & WFO & STATEOFFIC & ZONENAMES & LATITUDE & LONGITUDE & LATITUDE\_E & LONGITUDE\_ & REMARKS & REFNUM \\ 
  \hline
  1 & 1.00 & 4/18/1950 0:00:00 & 0130 & CST & 97.00 & MOBILE & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 14.00 & 100.00 & 3.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 15.00 & 25.00 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3040.00 & 8812.00 & 3051.00 & 8806.00 &  & 1.00 \\ 
  2 & 1.00 & 4/18/1950 0:00:00 & 0145 & CST & 3.00 & BALDWIN & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 2.00 & 150.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3042.00 & 8755.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 2.00 \\ 
  3 & 1.00 & 2/20/1951 0:00:00 & 1600 & CST & 57.00 & FAYETTE & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 0.10 & 123.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.00 & 25.00 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3340.00 & 8742.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 3.00 \\ 
  4 & 1.00 & 6/8/1951 0:00:00 & 0900 & CST & 89.00 & MADISON & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 0.00 & 100.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3458.00 & 8626.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 4.00 \\ 
  5 & 1.00 & 11/15/1951 0:00:00 & 1500 & CST & 43.00 & CULLMAN & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 0.00 & 150.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3412.00 & 8642.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 5.00 \\ 
  6 & 1.00 & 11/15/1951 0:00:00 & 2000 & CST & 77.00 & LAUDERDALE & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 1.50 & 177.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 6.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3450.00 & 8748.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 6.00 \\ 
% border
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}`. Just

```
\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont
```

suffices.