# How to use \scalebox on table to avoid table cutting off from page?

Tags: tables, scalebox

### 1

Suppose I load the following packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength\textwidth{6.5in}
\setlength\textheight{10in}\setlength\oddsidemargin{(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2 - 1in}
\setlength\topmargin{(\paperheight-\textheight-\headheight-\headsep-\footskip)/2 - 1in}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, array}
\usepackage{tabu, colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\minted}{\VerbatimEnvironment}{\VerbatimEnvironment\let\itshape\relax}{}{}
\usemintedstyle{bw}
```

### 2

How do I scale down my table without producing errors?

```
\scalebox{0.5}{
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{qcr}
\begin{tabular}{rrlllrlllrllllrlrllrrrrrrrlrllllrrrrlr}
% border
 & STATE\_\_ & BGN\_DATE & BGN\_TIME & TIME\_ZONE & COUNTY & COUNTYNAME & STATE & EVTYPE & BGN\_RANGE & BGN\_AZI & BGN\_LOCATI & END\_DATE & END\_TIME & COUNTY\_END & COUNTYENDN & END\_RANGE & END\_AZI & END\_LOCATI & LENGTH & WIDTH & F & MAG & FATALITIES & INJURIES & PROPDMG & PROPDMGEXP & CROPDMG & CROPDMGEXP & WFO & STATEOFFIC & ZONENAMES & LATITUDE & LONGITUDE & LATITUDE\_E & LONGITUDE\_ & REMARKS & REFNUM \\ 
  \hline
  1 & 1.00 & 4/18/1950 0:00:00 & 0130 & CST & 97.00 & MOBILE & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 14.00 & 100.00 & 3.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 15.00 & 25.00 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3040.00 & 8812.00 & 3051.00 & 8806.00 &  & 1.00 \\ 
  2 & 1.00 & 4/18/1950 0:00:00 & 0145 & CST & 3.00 & BALDWIN & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 2.00 & 150.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3042.00 & 8755.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 2.00 \\ 
  3 & 1.00 & 2/20/1951 0:00:00 & 1600 & CST & 57.00 & FAYETTE & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 0.10 & 123.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.00 & 25.00 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3340.00 & 8742.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 3.00 \\ 
  4 & 1.00 & 6/8/1951 0:00:00 & 0900 & CST & 89.00 & MADISON & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 0.00 & 100.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3458.00 & 8626.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 4.00 \\ 
  5 & 1.00 & 11/15/1951 0:00:00 & 1500 & CST & 43.00 & CULLMAN & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 0.00 & 150.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3412.00 & 8642.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 5.00 \\ 
  6 & 1.00 & 11/15/1951 0:00:00 & 2000 & CST & 77.00 & LAUDERDALE & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 1.50 & 177.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 6.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3450.00 & 8748.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 6.00 \\ 
% border
\end{tabular}
\end{table} }
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength\textwidth{6.5in}
\setlength\textheight{10in}\setlength\oddsidemargin{(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2 - 1in}
\setlength\topmargin{(\paperheight-\textheight-\headheight-\headsep-\footskip)/2 - 1in}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, array}
\usepackage{tabu, colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\minted}{\VerbatimEnvironment}{\VerbatimEnvironment\let\itshape\relax}{}{}
\usemintedstyle{bw}

\scalebox{0.5}{
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{qcr}
\begin{tabular}{rrlllrlllrllllrlrllrrrrrrrlrllllrrrrlr}
% border
 & STATE\_\_ & BGN\_DATE & BGN\_TIME & TIME\_ZONE & COUNTY & COUNTYNAME & STATE & EVTYPE & BGN\_RANGE & BGN\_AZI & BGN\_LOCATI & END\_DATE & END\_TIME & COUNTY\_END & COUNTYENDN & END\_RANGE & END\_AZI & END\_LOCATI & LENGTH & WIDTH & F & MAG & FATALITIES & INJURIES & PROPDMG & PROPDMGEXP & CROPDMG & CROPDMGEXP & WFO & STATEOFFIC & ZONENAMES & LATITUDE & LONGITUDE & LATITUDE\_E & LONGITUDE\_ & REMARKS & REFNUM \\ 
  \hline
  1 & 1.00 & 4/18/1950 0:00:00 & 0130 & CST & 97.00 & MOBILE & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 14.00 & 100.00 & 3.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 15.00 & 25.00 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3040.00 & 8812.00 & 3051.00 & 8806.00 &  & 1.00 \\ 
  2 & 1.00 & 4/18/1950 0:00:00 & 0145 & CST & 3.00 & BALDWIN & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 2.00 & 150.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3042.00 & 8755.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 2.00 \\ 
  3 & 1.00 & 2/20/1951 0:00:00 & 1600 & CST & 57.00 & FAYETTE & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 0.10 & 123.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.00 & 25.00 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3340.00 & 8742.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 3.00 \\ 
  4 & 1.00 & 6/8/1951 0:00:00 & 0900 & CST & 89.00 & MADISON & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 0.00 & 100.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3458.00 & 8626.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 4.00 \\ 
  5 & 1.00 & 11/15/1951 0:00:00 & 1500 & CST & 43.00 & CULLMAN & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 0.00 & 150.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3412.00 & 8642.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 5.00 \\ 
  6 & 1.00 & 11/15/1951 0:00:00 & 2000 & CST & 77.00 & LAUDERDALE & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 1.50 & 177.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 6.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3450.00 & 8748.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 6.00 \\ 
% border
\end{tabular}
\end{table} }
```

Comment: only scale tables as a last resort (and even then don't do it) it produces inconsistent and possibly unreadably small font sizes. Choose one of the standard sizes such as `\small` or `\footnotesize` if you need smaller fonts

Comment: it helps if you post the code as a single complete document so we can see the issue and test answers rather than having to paste together the separate fragments

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will edit now.

Comment: better don't use the tabu package, it is broken. See the readme here: https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu

Comment: And don't use minted in a minimal example if it is not relevant. It requires --shell-escape, and I don't like to use if it is not absolutly necessary.

Comment: your "full code" (also in your answer) will not work as posted, it is missing `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` it really does help if you post complete examples, without unrelated packages.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted some columns and replaced with ellipses:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength\textwidth{6.5in}
\setlength\textheight{10in}\setlength\oddsidemargin{(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2 - 1in}
\setlength\topmargin{(\paperheight-\textheight-\headheight-\headsep-\footskip)/2 - 1in}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, array}
\usepackage{tabu, colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usemintedstyle{bw}


\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{qcr}
\ttfamily
\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{gray!5}
\begin{tabular}{rrlllrlllrllllrlrllrrrrrrrlrllllrrrrlr}
% border
 & STATE\_\_ & BGN\_DATE & BGN\_TIME & TIME\_ZONE & COUNTY & COUNTYNAME & STATE & ... & REFNUM \\ 
  \hline
  1 & 1.00 & 4/18/1950 0:00:00 & 0130 & CST & 97.00 & MOBILE & AL & ... & 1.00 \\ 
  2 & 1.00 & 4/18/1950 0:00:00 & 0145 & CST & 3.00 & BALDWIN & AL & ... & 2.00 \\ 
  3 & 1.00 & 2/20/1951 0:00:00 & 1600 & CST & 57.00 & FAYETTE & AL & ... & 3.00 \\ 
  4 & 1.00 & 6/8/1951 0:00:00 & 0900 & CST & 89.00 & MADISON & AL & ... & 4.00 \\ 
  5 & 1.00 & 11/15/1951 0:00:00 & 1500 & CST & 43.00 & CULLMAN & AL & ... & 5.00 \\ 
  6 & 1.00 & 11/15/1951 0:00:00 & 2000 & CST & 77.00 & LAUDERDALE & AL & ... & 6.00 \\ 
% border
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: well yes that's far more readable but only you could have given this answer, it's hard for anyone else to answer a "make it fit"  question by saying "discard half the data" :-) But +1 anyway as it certainly looks more readable than my suggestion.

Comment: Do the `0:00:00` have any special meaning?

Comment: @Bernard `bgn_date` is part of a raw data frame I downloaded using `r`. Its class format is in `as.character` and the actual format of the data is in `dd/mm/yyyy_hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: I thought it would look better (and be more readable) if it were split into two columns, if that is not meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be hard to get that much data into a single table, you can make it fit, but think about anyone trying to read this, especially if on paper where you can not zoom in.

Avoid scaling tables, if you really must I'd rotate the table and use a smaller font size:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength\textwidth{6.5in}
\setlength\textheight{10in}\setlength\oddsidemargin{(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2 - 1in}
\setlength\topmargin{(\paperheight-\textheight-\headheight-\headsep-\footskip)/2 - 1in}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, array,graphicx}
\newcommand\hd[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\bfseries #1 }}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\tiny
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{qcr}
\rotatebox{90}{\begin{tabular}{rrlllrlllrllllrlrllrrrrrrrlrllllrrrrlr}
% border
 & \hd{STATE\_\_} & \hd{BGN\_DATE} & \hd{BGN\_TIME} & \hd{TIME\_ZONE} & \hd{COUNTY} & \hd{COUNTYNAME} &
 \hd{STATE} & \hd{EVTYPE} & \hd{BGN\_RANGE} & \hd{BGN\_AZI} & \hd{BGN\_LOCATI} & \hd{END\_DATE} & \hd{END\_TIME} &
 \hd{COUNTY\_END} & \hd{COUNTYENDN} & \hd{END\_RANGE} & \hd{END\_AZI} & \hd{END\_LOCATI} & \hd{LENGTH} & \hd{WIDTH} &
 \hd{F} & \hd{MAG} & \hd{FATALITIES} & \hd{INJURIES} & \hd{PROPDMG} & \hd{PROPDMGEXP} & \hd{CROPDMG} & \hd{CROPDMGEXP} &
 \hd{WFO} & \hd{STATEOFFIC} & \hd{ZONENAMES} & \hd{LATITUDE} & \hd{LONGITUDE} & \hd{LATITUDE\_E} & \hd{LONGITUDE\_} &
 \hd{REMARKS} & \hd{REFNUM} \\ 
  \hline
  1 & 1.00 & 4/18/1950 0:00:00 & 0130 & CST & 97.00 & MOBILE & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 14.00 & 100.00 & 3.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 15.00 & 25.00 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3040.00 & 8812.00 & 3051.00 & 8806.00 &  & 1.00 \\ 
  2 & 1.00 & 4/18/1950 0:00:00 & 0145 & CST & 3.00 & BALDWIN & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 2.00 & 150.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3042.00 & 8755.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 2.00 \\ 
  3 & 1.00 & 2/20/1951 0:00:00 & 1600 & CST & 57.00 & FAYETTE & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 0.10 & 123.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.00 & 25.00 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3340.00 & 8742.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 3.00 \\ 
  4 & 1.00 & 6/8/1951 0:00:00 & 0900 & CST & 89.00 & MADISON & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 0.00 & 100.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3458.00 & 8626.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 4.00 \\ 
  5 & 1.00 & 11/15/1951 0:00:00 & 1500 & CST & 43.00 & CULLMAN & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 0.00 & 150.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3412.00 & 8642.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 5.00 \\ 
  6 & 1.00 & 11/15/1951 0:00:00 & 2000 & CST & 77.00 & LAUDERDALE & AL & TORNADO & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 0.00 &  & 0.00 &  &  & 1.50 & 177.00 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 6.00 & 2.50 & K & 0.00 &  &  &  &  & 3450.00 & 8748.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 &  & 6.00 \\ 
% border
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you gave me an idea. I will show in answer.